# Does there exist a prime ideal $\mathfrak q\notin X$ with $\mathfrak q\subseteq\bigcup_{\mathfrak p\in X}\mathfrak p$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I'm reading "Algebraic Number Theory" by Neukirch. The following paragraph is from P.70.

> To end this section, we now want to compare a Dedekind domain $\mathcal O$ to the ring
> $$\mathcal O(X)=\{ \frac{f}{g}|f,g\in\mathcal O,g\not\equiv 0\mod\mathfrak p\text{ for } \mathfrak p\in X\}$$
> where $X$ is a set of prime ideals $\neq 0$ of $\mathcal O$ which contains almost all prime ideals of $\mathcal O$. By (11.1), the prime ideals $\neq 0$ of $\mathcal O(X)$ are given as $\mathfrak p_X=\mathfrak p\mathcal O(X)$, for $\mathfrak p\in X$.

My question: Does there exist a prime ideal $\mathfrak q\neq 0$ of $\mathcal O$ such that $\mathfrak q\notin X$ and $\mathfrak q\subseteq\bigcup_{\mathfrak p\in X}\mathfrak p$?

Answer (score 2):

This question is sort of unrelated to the Neukirch quoted, but it is interesting in its own right. In fact, it turned out to be much deeper than I originally thought, happy I read it!

The answer is **no** in number rings, no matter the choice of $\mathcal{O}$ and $X$ (unless $X$ is all the primes), and **possibly** in general Dedekind domains. When the answer is negative, the intuition comes from the integers: No matter how you pick $X$, the union of the ideals in X will never contain the missing prime.

More formally, when $\mathcal{O}$ is a PID, take any $X$ and any $\mathfrak{q}=(q)\notin X$. If $\mathfrak{q}\subseteq \bigcup_{\mathfrak{p}\in X}\mathfrak{p}$, then $q\in \frak{p}$ for some $\frak{p}$, and so $\frak{q}\subseteq p$. As prime ideals in Dedekind domains are maximal, we get $\frak{q}=p$, a contradiction.

First, let me deal with number rings (which of course is Neukirch's primary motivation when dealing with Dedekind domains). When $\mathcal{O}$ is not a PID, the argument is slightly more involved. If you are free to choose $X$, you can of course always choose it such that we only leave out a few principal ideals, and then we are reduced to the case above. Note that there always exist principal prime ideals in number rings, e.g. essentially following from Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions.

But given an arbitrary choice of $X$ and $\frak{q}$, it is still false: Indeed, even if $\frak{q}$ is not principal, some power of $\frak{q}$ is (I will argue this in a moment). So if, say, $\mathfrak{q}^n=(a)$, then $a\notin \bigcup_{\mathfrak{p}\in X}\mathfrak{p}$. This follows from unique prime factorization: $a\in \mathfrak{p}\Leftrightarrow \mathfrak{p} \mid (a)$, but only $\frak{q}$ appears in its prime factorisation, and $\frak{p}\neq q$.

The only thing missing is arguing that for any prime ideal in a number ring, some power of the ideal is principal. This follows from the ideal class group being finite. Indeed, the ideal class group is essentially the free abelian group on the prime ideals, quotiented by the free abelian group on principal ideals (given in terms of their factorization in prime ideals). If we had a prime ideal such that no power of it was ever principal, we would have an infinite cyclic subgroup, making the group infinite.

EDIT: As was pointed out in a comment, the above proof fails for general Dedekind domains, in particular those with infinite class groups. In fact, the statement is false in general.

There exists Dedekind domains $\mathcal{O}$ with elements of the class group having infinite order, consider e.g. $\Bbb{C}[X,\sqrt{X^3-X}]$ with class group isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}/(\Bbb{Z}+i\Bbb{Z})$. This implies that there exists prime ideals of infinite order, meaning no power of such an ideal $\frak{q}$ is principal. This will give us an example of what the OP question asks: Pick $X$ to be the set of all prime ideals except $\frak{q}$. Now, since the prime factorisation of every ideal $(\alpha)$ for $\alpha\in \frak{q}$ contains another ideal than $\frak{q}$, we get that $\alpha\in\frak{p}$ for some $\frak{p}$, in particular $\alpha\in \bigcup_{\mathfrak{p}\in X}\frak{p}$. As $\alpha$ was arbitrary, $\mathfrak{q}\subset \bigcup_{\mathfrak{p}\in X}\frak{p}$.

Comment: For a Dedekind domain, the ideal class group may not be finite.

Comment: @Borntobeproud Ach, you are right. In fact, the conclusion is false in general Dedekind domains, but true in number rings. I will edit my answer accordingly.